# Should standard topology contain proper or improper subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I've seen some people define the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as:

$\mathcal{T} = \{U\subset \mathbb{R}^n: \forall u \in U, \exists r > 0 : B_r(u)\subset U\}$

and other people deine it as:

$\mathcal{T} = \{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n: \forall u \in U, \exists r > 0 : B_r(u)\subseteq U\}$

Are both acceptable? Why?

In the first case, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ has to be in the topology, that would imply that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an improper subset of itself. This makes some sense to me because if we take some arbitrary copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can always find an infinitesimally larger copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that the first copy is an improper subset of.

The second also case makes sense because $U$ is allowed to equal $\mathbb{R}^n$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think what's happening here is just that in the first definition, the symbol "$\subset$" is used with the same meaning as "$\subseteq$". A lot of authors use it this way.

Comment: If this is a question in which the precise meaning of symbols is a central point, it would be great it those meanings are spelled out in full.  In particular "$\subset$" is a tricky symbol used with different meanings all the time. Consider using "$\subsetneq$" which is less controversial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Both definitions are acceptable and give the exact same topology. The reason they are equivalent is: if $B_r(u) \subset U$ then $B_r(u) \subseteq U$, while if $B_r(u) \subseteq U$ then $B_{r/2}(u) \subset U$.
- The first definition does not imply that $\Bbb R^n$ is a proper subset of itself (a subset of $A$ that is not equal to $A$ is a proper, not improper, subset). It just says that some ball $B_r(u)$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb R^n$.
- "An infinitesimally larger copy of $\Bbb R^n$" doesn't make sense. I'm not saying this to be mean, but it's really important that people remove any notions from their heads that "infinite" just means "really big". $\Bbb R^n$ is unbounded and infinite in every direction; "expanding" or "shrinking" it results in the exact same set, not a larger or smaller copy of it.

Comment: If the symbol "$\subset$" really means "is a proper subset of", then the first definition cannot be acceptable since it does not include $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: good point ... personally I always use $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$ (and $\subsetneq$ explicitly when necessary)